# Memory leaks in delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

My controller get data from function in delegat:

```
 - (NSArray *)getChapters {
 NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //memory leak
  if (chapter_statement == nil) {
        const char *sql = "SELECT DISTINCT 'Глава '||chapter FROM verses WHERE book=? ORDER by chapter";
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &chapter_statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }

 sqlite3_bind_int(chapter_statement, 1, self.book);
 while (sqlite3_step(chapter_statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {                
  NSString *body = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(chapter_statement, 0)];    
  [list addObject:body];
  [body release];
 }

 sqlite3_reset(chapter_statement);
 return list;
}
```

and use it in controller:

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

 self.listChapters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[appDelegate getChapters]];

 [self.listChapters release];

}
```

Leaks shows a memory leak at : `NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`
If I do return like `return [list autorelease];` app crashes in `viewWillAppear`.
How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning `[list autorelease]` is the right thing to do.  Your problem is the `[body release]` which you don't need.  The -[NSString stringWithUTF8String:] returns an autoreleased NSString.  The explicit `[body release]` means the list has pointers to deallocated objects.

Delete the `[body release]` line and put back the `return [list autorelease]` and it should work.

You can also run the static analyzer (Cmd-shift-A) to ask the compiler to find other memory management issues like this one.

Comment: Yes, it's works, but now Leaks shows leak in
-[NSPlaceholderString initWithBytes:length:encoding:] in Foundation

Comment: I suspect that leak is coming from somewhere else.  If you haven't already, check out FMDB (http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/06/new_home_for_fmdb.html)  It is a basic Cocoa wrapper for Sqlite that could save you a lot of grief managing DB calls.

Answer (score 1):

You should autorelease in `getChapters` and you should not release `self.listChapters` in `viewWillAppear`. It's just about never a good idea to write `[self.something release]`, because then you're potentially deallocating an object that you still have assigned to that property.

I strongly recommend you read the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/). They're not lengthy or difficult, and once you read through and understand them, you will never even have to think about something like this again.

Answer (score 0):

Lets count!

1.) You allocate the leaking array here:

```
 NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

retainCount = 1.

2.) You add the array to another array here:

```
 self.listChapters = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[appDelegate getChapters]];
```

What the new array (listChapters) does is retaining your leaking array.

retainCount = 2.

3.) You release the array (listChapters) that contains the leaking array:

```
[self.listChapters release];
```

What listChapters does here is also releasing all containing objects once, including your leaking array. Also, all references to your leaking array are lost after this line.

retainCount = 1

Comment: The retain count might or might not absolutely be 1 or 2.  Never consider the absolute retain count, always consider the deltas.... i.e. alloc is +1, self.listChapters = is +1, -release is -1.